# Should fragment be standalone?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, mvvm

I'm writing an application in Android in which main activity contains a navigation drawer, which switches between a few different views (displaying data in various ways). Each view is a fragment.

My architecture of choice is something like MVVM - I have viewmodels for each activity, which contain logic of specific view and provide models. Views are responsible only for displaying models and handling user interaction.

Now, I'm wondering, whether fragments should be standalone objects or not? In terms: should they only serve as composite views consisting of some visual controls and be managed from main activity? Or should they have viewmodels on their own and whole logic and main activity should only handle showing and hiding them?

Pros of fragments being standalone are: better SRR (otherwise I'd have to implement logic of all fragments in main activity's viewmodel), simpler implementation (activity doesn't have to pass models to each fragment, possibly `switch`ing through them to check, which one is active) and reusability (I can very easily place fragments next to other and they will work correctly). The con is that I didn't see such architecture much in examples I saw. Usually main activity `findViewById`s pieces of fragments and put data there.

What is common solution for such a problem?

Comment: I do admit this is kinda vague without *any* sample code to know what you're talking about, but I think it's a bit extreme to downvote so heavily.

Comment: I never saw a point in including source code in such question, because it concerns general application architecture and not a specific problem. And yet, Alexandre managed to understand what I was asking about. I'd be glad to hear out all who downvoted the question.

Comment: I dunno, I voted up - I just don't see it through without the example code, but then again, that's because I'm not deep into MVVM :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fragment should have his own and whole logic and be totally activity independant so you can reuse them easily in other activities.

If you want the fragment to communicate with the parent activity, also called container, you can use an interface.

Tell me if you need a sample code or if you were only looking for some informations :)